# How do I Prevent scrolling in container within a blazor app?

Tags: javascript, html, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a container with a fixed height. The content of the container is a table which contains a numerous amount of items.

```html
<div class="fixed-height" @onkeydown:stopPropagation>
    <table class="table align-middle">
        <thead class="sticky-top bg-secondary" >
            <tr>
                <th>Art</th>
                <th>Kurzbezeichnung</th>
                <th>Identifier</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Strasse</th>
                <th>Ort</th>
                <th>Postleitzahl</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Data)
            {
                <tr id="@($"search-result{Data.IndexOf(item)}")" tabindex="@tabIndex"
                    @onfocus="() => SaveFocusState(item)"
                @onkeyup="async (e) => await OnRowKeyUpAsync(e, item, Data.IndexOf(item))"
                @onclick="async () => await OnItemClickedAsync(item)"
                @ondblclick="async() => await OnItemSelectedAsync(item)">
                    <td>@item.Art</td>
                    <td>@item.Kurzbezeichnung</td>
                    <td>@item.GetEindeutigeNummer()</td>
                    <td>@item.Name1</td>
                    <td>@item.Strasse</td>
                    <td>@item.Ort</td>
                    <td>@item.Postleitzahl</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Each of rows is reachable through the tab key on my keyboard. I also hooked up the `onkeyup` event on my table row to change the focus using the arrow keys.

```cs
private async Task OnRowKeyUpAsync(KeyboardEventArgs e, Stammdatensatz item, int tabIndex)
{
    var test = e.Code;
    if(e.Code == "ArrowDown" || e.Key == "ArrowDown")
    {
        if(tabIndex < Data.Count)
        {
            int newIndex = tabIndex + 1;
            await jsRuntime.FocusByIdAsync($"search-result{newIndex}");
        }
    }
    else if (e.Code == "ArrowUp" || e.Key == "ArrowUp")
    {
        if(tabIndex > 0)
        {
            int newIndex = tabIndex - 1;
            await jsRuntime.FocusByIdAsync($"search-result{newIndex}");
        }
    }
    else if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Key == "Enter")
    {
        await OnItemSelectedAsync(item);
    }


}
```

My only issue now is that the fixed height div starts scrolling whenever I press the down or up arrow. How can I prevent this?

I already tried all sorts of combiniations of `:stopPropagation` and `:preventDevault` on my div.

Comment: did you also try both `:stopPropagation` and `:preventDevault` together?